# Facebook - How can i make API calls on behalf of a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Okay.. i got the offline access session key

Can some please tell me how can i update my FB status using the offline access session key i have ?

Looked in the Graph API and PHP SDK  but nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say 'offline access session key' you mean the oauth access token.

Take a look at the 'Publishing to Facebook' section here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing

There is even a short example using `curl`:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
 -F 'body=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```